# How to get the length of a report's GroupingLevel array in VBA

Tags: arrays, ms-access, vba

My app allows users to sort a report by an arbitrary number of options.  I need my VBA code to check if a GroupLevel already exists, so that I can add it in case the report does not have a particular group level.  (Obviously, if the GroupLevel already exists, I change it's control to the one specified by the user.  That part works.)

When I treat GroupLevel as an array like so:

```
If Me.Child0.Report.GroupLevel.Level < Grouping_Level Then
```

I get a compiler error pointing to the .GroupLevel saying:

> "Argument not optional"

If instead I test for a NULL value at the proposed grouping level like so:

```
If IsNull(Me.Child0.Report.GroupLevel(Grouping_Level)) Then
```

I get this error message:

> "There is no sorting or grouping field or expression defined for the
>   group level number you used"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't reference the GroupLevel as whole, have to reference each level by index. I am not seeing Level as a property of GroupLevel. Referencing a GroupLevel index that doesn't exist along with a GroupLevel property will trigger run-time error 2464.
`Me.Child0.Report.GroupLevel(Grouping_Level).ControlSource`
So only approach I can see is to handle the error if it is triggered.
Review [Allen Browne error handler](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-23a.html)